# How to make another image text appear on top of the existing image texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, shaders, transparency, texture-painting

[image]

It's connected like this.

I want to add a heart-shaped image to a specific part.
I want to turn the heart pattern on and off.

so I have three questions.
[image]

first, I connected it like this.

Is this the right way to connect?

second, If i do this, the heart color mixes.

Can't you make the color you want come out without mixing it?
[image]
Third, I used an image of a transparent background

but it's black, and because of that

the parts other than hearts mixed

can't you get rid of the black background?

Comment: Hello could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?

Comment: Connect the alpha output socket of the Image Texture with an alpha channel (cube.png) to the input socket of the mix node.

Comment: I guess @Leander means the *Fac* input of the *Mix* node.